# Barlow knife quote meaning in Mark Twain's Adventures of Tom Sawyer

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

> True, the knife would not cut
>   anything, but it was a "sure-enough" Barlow, and there was
>   inconceivable grandeur in that - though where the Western boys ever
>   got the idea that such a weapon could possibly be counterfeited to its
>   injury, is an imposing mystery and will always remain so, perhaps.

Doesn't seem to be your normal construct in regards to **"...such a weapon could possibly be counterfeited to its injury..."**

What does "**to its injury**" mean here?

Comment: The narrator is saying that the Barlow knife brand supplies products of such a poor quality that the brand would suffer no loss of reputation if anyone were to counterfeit them as the counterfeits could not be worse than the original. 'counterfeited to its injury' can be understood as 'counterfeited to a standard which would damage the brand reputation.'

Comment: @Spagirl I would vote up that answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't know where to begin looking for adequate citations or references to support it, which is why I left it as a comment.